# How to adjust menu's margin and padding without items being out of place

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to reduce the size of the drop down menus to the same as the buttons. Adjusting either the padding or margin would move the items out of place and close themselves when I try to hover over it. I'd like to know what is causing this. Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwhXa/1/)
Any help would be great.

CSS:

```
.sort ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  float:right;

}
.sort ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #FF5C00 url(http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/Games/SoManySales/Joint%20Supplement/alert-overlay_zpsf561d19b.png) repeat-x;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  color:#fff;
}
.sort ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
.sort ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.sort ul li ul li { 
  background: #FFDFDF; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  z-index:9999;
}
.sort ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
.sort ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}


.button, ul{ padding-left: 15px;}
.button { 
    list-style: none; cursor: pointer;
    float: left; margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: #039fd3; color: #fff; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;  
    -moz-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;  
    transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sort"><ul>
  <li>
    Sort AXXX
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>SXXXX</a></li>
      <li><a href='%#%'>AXXXx</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Sort BXXX
    <ul>
      <li><a href='%#%'>CXXXX</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

  <li>Sort C
    <ul>
      <li><a href='%#%'>WSXXXX</a></li>
       <li><a href='%#%'>SXXXX</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

    </ul></div>
```

Comment: do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9S47p/

Comment: @melc I mean I want to adjust the padding of the dropdown menu so that it doesn't look so much bigger than the buttons.

Comment: here is another example where the dropdown menu is similar in size to the buttons on the left http://jsfiddle.net/hfJc7/ , but i'm still not certain if this is what you are after.

Comment: @melc yours is very close. The other reason I was trying to adjust its `margin` is that I want the menu and the button to be at the same height. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: ok i see, just added an answer with explanations regarding the additions, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the op coding style, in order to adjust the width of the dropdown it is required to set a width value for the list items under `.sort` div. Also added paddings similar to the ones set to the blue buttons on the left.

```
.sort ul li{
    width:70px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Also it is necesary to adjust the top relative position of the sub menu to always be below the the main menu,

```
.sort ul li ul{
    top:100%;
}
```

To adjust the distance from the top of the menu to be the same as with the buttons, it is possible to tweak the top relative distance of the menu to achieve it.

The `ul` element containing the buttons is a block element and the list items within it are floated with a `margin-top` of `10px` and `padding-top` of `5px` so a total of `15px` from the top. The `ul` element within `div.sort` is floated to the right and has a `padding-top` of `5px` so with `margin-top` `10px` (i.e. 15-5) should be aligned with the buttons.

```
.sort > ul{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/fLSyE/

Answer (score 0):

First is, if you want your buttons and drop down menu to have the same size, just set the `width` to be the same. Here is an example(from your code):

```
.sort ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;                         /* set width of drop down menu to 100px */
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    /* SOME OTHER CODES FOLLOW */
}

.sort ul li {
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    width: 100px;                        /* also set the width of the menus to 100px */
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;

}
```

Hope it helps!